# C++14: Conversion between UTF-8/UTF-16 and native character encoding

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding

I have 4 closely related questions:

1. Does C++14 have a built-in mechanism for converting between UTF-8 and the systems native **multibyte encoding**, i.e., the multibyte encoding assumed by the `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char>` specialization (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt)?
2. Does C++14 have a built-in mechanism for converting between UTF-8 and the systems native **wide character encoding**, i.e., the wide character encoding assumed by the `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char>` specialization (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt)?
3. Same as question 1, but for UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.
4. Same as question 2, but for UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.

EDIT: I realize that a "yes" to any of these questions, effectively means "yes" to all 4, because C++14 clearly does provide ways of converting between UTF-8 and UTF-16 (`std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>`), as well as between native multibyte and native wide character encodings (`std::codecvt<wchar_t, char>`).

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, yes, but for the first I think you have to detour via the wide encoding. Also remember to set proper locale. The default, C locale, isn't usable.

Comment: Ok, can you provide a hint? I see no way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) and its inverse.

Comment: I always found C++'s character set conversions to be awkward and difficult to work with. `libiconv` is just as portable, and much easier to work with.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That solution only works in particular locales, and C++14 does not guarantee that such a locale exists, much less how to get access to such a locale, as far as I can see. I'm after something that is generic, and not depending on platform specificities.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*libiconv is just as portable, and much easier to work with.*" But it doesn't know anything about narrow or wide character sets, as those are compiler specific.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see your point, but I'm after something generic that makes no assumptions beyond those guaranteed by C++14.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege: If you're looking for something generic, you shouldn't be using narrow or wide characters. You should be using strings with a specific encoding to them.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't see how that solves my problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @NicolBolas Or do you mean that the answer to my question is "No, it cannot be done in a generic way with what is provided by C++14"?

Comment: See the table documented on cppreference.com for [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) and [`std::wstring_convert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert), it shows the available standard conversions.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege: If I were solving your problem, I'd be posting an answer. I'm trying to get you to avoid the problem entirely by encouraging you not to rely on unreliable things. If you want strings in a known, well-defined state, encode them in a Unicode encoding.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Awesome. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @NicolBolas `libiconv` **does** know about platform-specific narrow and wide encodings: "*Locale dependent, in terms of `char` or `wchar_t` (with machine dependent endianness and alignment, and with OS and locale dependent semantics*"

Comment: You can't have a completely generic solution because the standard can not allow for every possible platform mb character encoding. Therefore it lets the platform implementation do the right thing for it. I suspect `mbstowcs` will be fine if you use `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` to set the user's current locale, but I have not tested that on other platforms.

Comment: @Galik That is what I expected, but it turns out that the particular conversions that I am asking about can be done in a completely generic way with what is provided by C++14.  In particular, one can use `std::mbrtoc32()` and `std::c32rtomb()` to convert between UCS-4 and the native multibyte encoding. Then, for example, one can use `std::codecvt_utf8` to convert between UCS-4 and UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

> the systems native multibyte encoding, i.e., the multibyte encoding assumed by the `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char>` specialization

There is confusion, possibly due to misleading wording on cppreference (my fault, now fixed to match the standard and reality); in the existing implementations (libc++ and libstdc++), the locale-independent codecvt specialization `codecvt<wchar_t, char>` does not deal with any multibyte encodings. The standard wording is "native character sets for narrow and wide characters.", and the existing implementations took that to mean 1:1 conversions only, like what btowc/wctob do in C:

```
template<class F> struct facet : F { using F::F; ~facet() {} };
facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> fp;
std::cout << fp.max_length() << '\n'; // prints 1 in libc++ and libstdc++
```

in fact, here's the [libc++ implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/locale.cpp#L1439-L1447)

In every useful context, multibyte encoding is either an encoding specified by a locale-provided codecvt facet, or by a custom codecvt facet, or UTF-8 (provided by the `std::codecvt_utf8*` facets). Meaning,

> between UTF-8 and the systems native multibyte encoding

means "between UTF-8 and a multibyte encoding specified by a locale"

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <cassert>

template<class F> struct myFacet : F { using F::F; ~myFacet() {} };
int main()
{
    std::string in = u8"水"; // UTF-8
    // utf8 to wide (could've used en_US.utf8, but this one exists as-is)
    std::wstring ws = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>{}.from_bytes(in);
    assert(ws == L"水");
    // wide to another mb (have to use a named locale now)
    typedef myFacet<std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> F;
    std::string out = std::wstring_convert<F>{ new F("zh_CN.gb18030") }.to_bytes(ws);
    assert(out == "\xcb\xae");
}
```

> Does C++14 have a built-in mechanism for converting between UTF-8 and the systems native wide character encoding

Native wide is effectively defined to be Unicode or (as on Windows) its arbitrary subset, and that's what you get from [std::codecvt_utf8](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8). A hostile implementation could possibly have a wchar_t holding values numerically different from the Unicode code points, as long as they map 1:1, but given that they must be equal to them for the basic charset, it is unrealistic.